# SmtpClient Text only version of mail body is missing apostrophe

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to send an email through the SmtpClient.

The text only part of the received email is missing all the apostrophes.

For instance, the following text (in french):

> Bonjour, l’administrateur de votre organisation a validé votre demande d’accès à la plateforme.

Is received as

> Bonjour, l administrateur de votre organisation a validé votre demande d accès à la plateforme.

I only have the problem with ASP.Net, **the result is fine in a .NET Core 3.1 Console application**.

What can be the source of this problem?

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the code

```
using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient
{
          Host = @"smtp.myhost.net",
})
            {
string body = @"Bonjour, l’administrateur de votre organisation a validé votre demande d’accès à la plateforme.";
await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(
                            "noreply@mydomain.com",
                            @"dest@domain.fr",
                            string.Empty,
                            body)
                            .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
            }
```

---

EDIT : Problem solved by replacing the apostrophes by the ASCII versions.

Comment: Can you post the code where you create the smtp client and send the message?

Comment: Did you properly encode the email? Emails can only contain ASCII characters, everything not US-ASCII, needs to be encoded (utf8, quoted-printable etc)

Comment: You can try set DeliveryFormat = SmtpDeliveryFormat.International on smtpClient arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using other overloaded function `SendMailAsync(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message)` in which you can define `encoding` as `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`for your mail message.

```
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("dest@domain.fr");
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("noreply@mydomain.com");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.Body = @"Bonjour, l’administrateur de votre organisation 
                    a validé votre demande d’accès à la plateforme.";
message.BodyEncoding =  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
message.Subject = "some text";
message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Then `SendMailAsync` will be like:

```
await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message)
      .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
```

Comment: Using this code, I'm able to reproduce the problem in the console application and with ASP.NET.

Comment: @OlivierMATROT That's good. May be you can try different `Encoding` option and see which works for you. I'm surprised that `UTF8` is not helping you.

Comment: The problem was not the encoding but the apostrophe itself. I must have pasted the text from somewhere to end up with a rounded apostrophe (’) instead of a straight one ('). It woks with a straight one.